# What would be the best/standard approach for creating HTML controls dynamically using ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-5

I got a new project in which I have to create HTML controls dynamically in a view based on a setting stored in a database. I thought,there could be two different approaches

(1) Using **jQuery**:

```
function bindControls(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ViewDef/GetControls",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            var res = response.d;
            if (res.trim() != "") {
                var data = $.parseJSON(res);
                $("#dvQuota").html("");
                var dvQuota = $("#dvQuota");
                $("#dvControls").addClass("ui-main");
                var cType = "";
                var cID = "";
                if (data.length > 0) {
                    $.each(data, function (i) {
                        cType = data[i].cType;
                        cID = data[i].cID;
                        switch (cType) {
                            case "TextBox":
                                $(dvQuota).append("<input type='text' id='" + cID + "' class='c1'/>");
                                break;
                            case "DROPDOWN":
                                $(dvQuota).append("<select type='text' id='" + cID + "' class='c1'></select>");
                                //logic for binding drop down list
                                break;
                        }

                    });
                }
            }
            }
        });
    }
```

2) Using **C#**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ds.Table[0].Length; i++)
    {
            <div>
                //logic for generating Controls
            </div>
    }
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

As I am new to MVC, I'm unable to decide. Would request you all please suggest best approach?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If it's good for the page-load, i.e. you don't need to add additional dynamic controls after the response has already been sent to the client, then go with C#. While relatively rare, not everyone has JavaScript enabled and certain screen-readers to this day cannot parse JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use JQuery approach in a way that you supplied in the question all the controls are added after initial page load - so there is a chance that used is going to see the page without controls. Using C# approach will render all the controls on a server and send a complete page to the user.

I personally prefer C# approach simply because there is less code to write. And you have a lot of HtmlHelpers such as Html.TextBox, Html.DropDown and etc. that could make your life a little easier

Comment: dear Alex thank you so much for your response,Is there any another approach ?

Comment: Well, you could combine both approaches : create a partial view that is going to contain all your controls and fetch it through ajax. You will be getting a rendered html as an ajax response so you could simply insert it into your page.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer jQuery because that way you're only passing data back and forth with the server and not HTML.

One thing I would recommend in your code to improve performance is to not 'append' inside a loop.  See below, instead of appending inside the $.each loop, add that html to a string or something and once the loop ends $(dvQuota).append or $(dvQuota).innerHTML.

Also there is some small difference between using jQuery's $.each loop vs a regular javascript for loop in performance terms.

```
 $.each(data, function (i) {
                        cType = data[i].cType;
                        cID = data[i].cID;
                        switch (cType) {
                            case "TextBox":
                                $(dvQuota).append("<input type='text' id='" + cID + "' class='c1'/>");
                                break;
                            case "DROPDOWN":
                                $(dvQuota).append("<select type='text' id='" + cID + "' class='c1'></select>");
                                //logic for binding drop down list
                                break;
                        }

                    });

// append here

// create events here
$('select .c1').change(function(){
  if (this.id === 'something')
{
    // do something
}
});
```

Comment: Dear Sam,Thanks a lot for your response.IF I will append my HTML to DOM at last(instead of adding one by one )  then how could I bind drop down, other events like change,blur  to controls?Don't you think so I have to write one more loop and that could also degrade performance.

Comment: I would create one event (after the big append) for all selects that have class = c1.  I've added a change to reflect this in my code above.